# How to increment hex in perl

Tags: perl

**CODE**

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $mv = 41;
my $tmp =1;
while($tmp<26)
{
print  chr (hex($mv++));
print "\n";
$tmp++;
}
```

**OUTPUT**
ABCDEFGHIPQRSTUVWXY`abcde

Code  generate English character set

Issue

Few characters are missing "J->O && Z "

Reason  J hex value is 4a

How to increment the hex value in perl or any another way to generate the character set?

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation for `hex`. You seem to think it does the opposite of what it actually does.

Comment: More to the point, there's no such thing as a "hex value"; hexidecimal is one way to represent an integer. It's only useful for display or input, not for internal use. 0x20 and 41 are the exact same value; trying to convert to 0x20 and then call `chr` on that is meaningless.

Comment: Generating the character set in perl is as easy as `'A'..'Z'`. Don't know why you need a loop...

Comment: @Diego the loop is to assign numeric value to the character           for example A=1,B=2 that  part is not included in the code

Comment: The increment operator has special magic that it uses based on what it thinks it is incrementing. http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/1220

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to a comment you left, your end goal appears to be to produce the mapping A=1,B=2. Here's code to achieve that:

```
my @symbols = 'A'..'Z';
my %map = map { $symbols[$_] => $_+1 } 0..$#symbols;
```

Or (less flexible):

```
my %map = map { $_ => ord($_)-ord('A')+1 } 'A'..'Z';
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want

```
for my $i (65..122) {
    print chr($i);
}
```

Also you may like

```
for my $char ("a".."z", "A".."Z") {
    print $char;
}
```

Comment: one question why the range (65..122)                                  [link]http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?unicodeinhtml=hex in the document the hex value start from 41

Comment: Because 41 there it's hex value and `chr()` accepts numeric value. You can just use `0x41 .. 0x7a` (or other values from hexadecimal representations) instead of `65..122`

Comment: @Amith, Hex is a representation, a way of displaying a number. "41 hex" is a way of displaying sixty-five. In Perl, you can create a scalar that contains sixty-five using `65`, `64+1`, `0x41`, `0101`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside your actual stated goal (the mapping of characters to codes), the problem here is that `$mv` is not a hexadecimal value, it's a decimal value that you stringify and treat as hexadecimal. That means that the next value after 49 is 50, not 4a. If `$mv` were in hex from the outset, you wouldn't have this problem (and you wouldn't need the call to `hex()`, either). If you declare `$mv` as so:

```
$mv = 0x41;
```

then you will find that the value 49 is correctly followed by 4a. Using your code example:

```
my $mv = 0x41;
my $tmp = 1;
while ($tmp < 26)
{
    print chr($mv++);
    print "\n";
    $tmp++;
}
```

You should get the original intended results.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
print chr for (65..90);
```